# wkhtmltoimage rendered only bar instead full page

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I have a problem with wkhtmltoimage 12.4 and the newest alpha version. I tried to save H&M webpage, but I only get a little bar instead full webpage. I tried use many of switches to change settings but nothing works. Is there any solution for achieve correctly webpage in png format? Thanks very much.
[image: H&m webpage]

That is saved website...